# How to override templates for WooCommerce Subscriptions?

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, subscription

I'm trying to override some template files for WC Subscriptions.

The template file I'm trying to override is:

```
plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/templates/myaccount/subscription-details.php
```

I have tried placing it in:

```
themes/{my-theme}/woocommerce/myaccount/subscription-details.php
```

and

```
themes/{my-theme}/woocommerce-subscriptions/myaccount/subscription-details.php
```

But neither is getting overridden. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a caching issue that was preventing the template from being loaded.

Place template here to override:

```
themes/{my-theme}/woocommerce/myaccount/subscription-details.php
```